# IOS swift how can I populate my TableView with Json data being returned

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have just started working with Swift and am able to do some basic things. Right now I am trying to populate my UITableView with Json Data that I am successfully retrieving. Right now I have this simple Table that looks like this

[image]

That is a basic TableView that I was able to create with this code

```
  @IBOutlet var StreamsTableView: UITableView!

    let groceries = ["Fish","lobster","Rice","Beans"]




     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
       let mycell:UITableViewCell = StreamsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototype1", for: indexPath)

        mycell.textLabel?.text = groceries[indexPath.row]
        return mycell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return groceries.count
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        StreamsTableView.dataSource = self
}
```

I now have a JsonRequest that I am completing successfully using this code below

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        StreamsTableView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        var names = [String]()
        let urlString = "http://localhost:8000/streams"

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                do {

                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                    if let Streams = parsedData["Streams"] as! [AnyObject]? {

                    for Stream in Streams {
                        if let post = Stream["post"] as? String {
                            names.append(post)
                        }
                        }
                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
        print(names)
            }

        }).resume()

    }
```

What I essentially like to do is put the value of

```
let post = Stream["post"] as? String
```

inside the TableView instead of the Groceries array . As I stated before the value is coming back from the Json, I just have not found any way that I could put that value inside the TableView any help would be great . I am using swift 3.0 .

Comment: Call `StreamsTableView.reloadData` after `for Stream in Streams {` loop

Comment: @Mr.Bista Make sure it is called on the main queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reloading data code

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    StreamsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

just after your for loop

```
for Stream in Streams { ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was perfect

Answer (score 1):

```
if let Streams = parsedData["Streams"] as! [AnyObject]? {

                for Stream in Streams {
                    if let post = Stream["post"] as? String {
                        names.append(post)
                    }
                }
            }

            StreamsTableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score -1):

After loop done

StreamsTableView.reloadData()

update:

mycell.textLabel?.text = groceries[indexPath.row]

to

mycell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]